# how to use a variable as object?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

this is the function in class that i use

```
public function content($search) {
        $this->dbconnection();
        $search = mysql_real_escape_string($search);

        $q= mysql_query("SELECT title FROM xx WHERE title LIKE '%$search%'");
        $s = mysql_fetch_array($q);
        foreach ($s as $key => $val) {
            $$key = $val;
        }

    }
```

and on index.php file

```
$cl= new Class;
$test = $cl->content('cloud');
```

and question is

how can i echo the variable which i set inside foreach loop?

`$test->title;` < this is not working for sure, but this explains the thing that i am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the array as an object:

```
public function content($search)
{
    $this->dbconnection();
    $search = mysql_real_escape_string($search);

    $q = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM xx WHERE title LIKE '%$search%'");
    $s = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);

    return (object)$s;
}
```

Then in your code:

```
$cl= new Class;
$content = $cl->content('cloud');
echo $content->title;
```

Alternatively, you could fetch the row as an object by using [mysql_fetch_object](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php)

Comment: Was also going to suggest mysql_fetch_object: http://us2.php.net/mysql_fetch_object

Answer (score 1):

Set a public property in your class and assign the title variable to it.  Add this to the top of your class:

```
public $title = '';
```

Then assign the variable in your foreach as such:

```
$this->title = $whatever;
```

Comment: alright but what if i change sql query like this `SELECT * FROM xx WHERE title LIKE '%$search%'` ? more than 10 variables will set by foreach

Comment: @adlawson: good catch!
ronnie Then declare the variable as an array and store each result within it

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand what you are trying to do in this code snippet.
Your function content() does not return a Value. So there is nothing saved in your $test Variable.
Your content() Function creates a bunch of Variables with the key Values received from the Query as Name. So if you want to get the Value of your "$title" Variable/key you just have to echo that.

Try:

```
echo $title;
```

after you have called the content() function. This should echo you the Value of the title you were searching for, provided your query returned something and "title" as a Key.
If you want to make something like:

```
$res = $classObject->content('cloud');
echo $res->title;
```

You will have to create such an Object, which has a title Attribute and return that in your Function.